# Recursive text search with grep and file patterns

Tags: command-line-interface, grep, search

Given this example folder structure:

```
/folder1/file1.txt
/folder1/file2.djd
/folder2/file3.txt
/folder2/file2.fha
```

How do I do a recursive text search on all `*.txt` files with `grep` from "/"?

(`"grep -r <pattern> *.txt"` fails when run from "/", since there are no `.txt` files in that folder.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

My version of GNU Grep has a switch for this:

```
grep -R --include='*.txt' $Pattern
```

Described as follows:

> ```
> --include=GLOB
> ```
>
> Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude).

Answer (score 20):

If you have a large number of files it would be useful to incorporate xargs into the command to avoid an 'Argument list too long' error.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print | xargs grep <pattern>
```

Comment: If there are spaces in any of the file or directory names, use this form:
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep <pattern>

Comment: And of course there's the issue of filenames that start with `-`.

Comment: `grep` is faster of `find`.

Answer (score 2):

you might be able to make use of your `zsh`'s `EXTENDED_GLOB` option ([docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html))

```
grep <pattern> **/*.txt
```

Comment: Only if OP is using zsh, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at ack at http://betterthangrep.com, which has facilities for selecting files to search by filetype.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec grep <pattern> {} \;
```

Comment: you might want to use "find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec grep <pattern> {} +" instead so that it rather behaves similiar the verision with from Mark Robinson - works only with GNU find to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Mannis answer would fork a new grep-process for every textfile. If you have *lots* of textfiles there, you might consider grepping every file first and pick the .txt-files when thats done:

```
grep -r <pattern> * | grep \.txt:
```

That's more disk-intensive, but might be faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2019 and there's no way I would still use grep for recursive text searching.

IMHO todays answers should include [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-file-types):

```
rg <pattern> -ttxt
```